# It the any proper way how to take a two byte elemetns from list, concat them, and convert them to integer

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list with 4 element which contain integers 
    data = [134, 2, 4, 170]
    hexdata = [0x86, 0x2, 0x4, 0xAA]

i need to get hex data from two last elements eg. (0x04 and 0xAA)
concatenate them to this view  0x04AA and convert to int
in the end i need to get integer with value = 1194.
i am stuck in this task/

```py
data = [134, 2, 4, 170]
for x in data:
    print("0x%x" % (x), end=" ")
print()
c = "0x%x%x" % (data[2], data[3])
print(c)
print(int(c))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "123.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(int(c))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x4aa'
```

Comment: The 3rd  element is '0x4' instead of '0x04'

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to bother with string formatting here - use [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) instead, eg:

```
data = [134, 2, 4, 170]
res = int.from_bytes(data[-2:], 'big')
# 1194
```

Comment: Thanks friend. This is exactly what I need. Your answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [134, 2, 4, 170]
result = data[-2] << 8 | data[-1]
```

Comment: bitshifting is even more elegant then multiplying by 256

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply the 4 accordingly and add it up? No need to go hex on it ...

```
data = [134, 2, 4, 170]

rv = data[2]*256 + data[3]  # 0x04AA == 0x04*256 + 0xAA

print(rv)
```

Output:

```
1194
```